# Getting rid of unused pointers in a pointers array : C++ Builder

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a Part class. And I created an array of pointers of type Part.

```
    const int SZ = 50;
    Part *myPart[SZ];
```

I then made a new instance of type Part inside the Part array at a random position between 0 and 50. A new instance is created every time a Button is pressed.

```
    int x = (rand() * SZ)/RAND_MAX + 0;
    myPart[x] = new Part(x);
```

I then put the result inside a List Box. This is executed when a second Button is pressed.

```
String str = "";

ListBox1->Clear();
for(int x = 0; x < SZ; x++)
{
    if(myPart[x])
    {
        str = IntToStr(myPart[x]->getId()) + ", ";
        str += myPart[x]->getStatus() + ", " + myPart[x]->getShelf() + ", ";
        str += IntToStr(myPart[x]->getQuantity());

        ListBox1->Items->Add(str);
    }
    else
    {
        ListBox1->Items->Add("- - - - - - - - -");
    }
}
```

The result will appear at different places (index positions) in the List Box.

Say I pressed the randomizing button 5 times, and thus have 5 results at different random positions in the list box, how do I "push" the 5 results to the top of the stack and get rid of the 45 remaining, unused pointers?

Comment: Why did you started with random positions if you wanted them to be on the top?

Comment: This would be much easier if you used `std::map<int, Part*>` instead of an array.

Comment: Is this part of a class exercise? Because this code is otherwise insane and nothing you would ever do in the real world.

Comment: @FirstStep     It's part of the exercise. Randomize, then push the results to the top. I suppose starting at the top would have been easy.     @ Rob K - Yes, it is. I'm starting with Programming

Comment: initialize the whole array with `null` values, then after your _5 times_ operation, iterate: whatever is not `null` -> _set on top_?

Comment: Use i for your counter instead of x

Comment: Not related, but `int x = (rand() * SZ)/RAND_MAX + 0;` has more then an issue: rand() * SZ may overflow, resulting in a negative value (2 complement), but in every case the division is an integer division, so x = 0. ' + 0;'. If you don't want to use <random> you can use: `int x = rand() % SZ;`

Comment: @Bob__ - the randomizing has never been an issue. It works perfectly for what it's supposed to do. It generates a random number from 0 - 49

Comment: @Josh Interesting. [It's not what I've experienced](https://ideone.com/FWfKFT), but again, it's unrelated to the question.

Comment: It is difficult to grasp what you want. Say instead you pushed the button 6 times. You already got rid of the other 45. Then the 6th would already be null!